# Intellij Vertx Debug Restart Race Condition

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, vert.x

I'm using Intellij to debug run a Vert.X 3 application and almost 50% of the time, when I press the restart button I get this error:

I press this button to rebuild/restart the app:

[image: restart image button]

`Apr 02, 2016 7:17:03 PM io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl
SEVERE: java.net.BindException: Address already in use`

Which means that the debugger hasn't killed the port and is starting it up again before it's ready. It's extremely variable.

My gradle debug is rather simple and I have checked the *Single instance only* option.

[image: intellij gradle debug configuration]

Does anyone know how to re-debug-run without causing this race condition?

Answer (score 4):

Your verticle must override the stop function using the `Future` version.

Something like:

```
public void stop(Future<Void> future) {
     httpServer.close(ar -> {
        if (ar.succeeeded()) { future.complete(); }
        else {
         future.fail(ar.cause());
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you shutting down your `HTTPServer` & `Verticle` properly and signaling to Vertx when it's all done?

I had this exact same issue (albeit in tests), but solved it by properly shutting down my server and verticle.

Here is some example code (Using the `Rx` version)

```
    @Override
    public void stop(Future<Void> stopFuture) {

        httpServer.closeObservable()
                .subscribe(
                        aVoid -> {
                        },
                        error -> {
                            logger.error("Could not shutdown HTTP Server ", error);
                            stopFuture.fail(error);
                        },
                        () -> {
                            logger.info("HTTP Server Shutdown");
                            stopFuture.complete();
                        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... but how would this work if I'm running it from a main function?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. If you use main to start and stop your `verticle` by `vertx.deployVerticle` & `vertx.undeploy` then the `undeploy` executes the stop function in your verticle, which should cleanly shutdown your http server.